# VBA, EXCEL Allow USER to login to webpage before scraping data

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

So I'm trying to setup a relatively simple scrape based off an intranet page at work to populate an excel Sheet.

Most of this I can do without a problem; but the problem is my company's intranet pages require you to login with a username and password, then a token key (we have hard tokens) AFTER you use username and password.

To make folks feel better I'd like to have VBA open up IE to the specific page, which will then route automatically to the login page to company intranet.

User will then login completely no pw/username/etc will be saved. Then once everything is logged in and the document title changes to something specific then the script starts working.

Hoping for assistance on this. Just where to start, all the how-tos and suggestions I've written have the pw entered then passed by the code, and I'm trying to completely avoid that.

Comment: Can you clarify: if you don't want the user to manually enter the login/pw and you don't want it to be saved anywhere, how do you propose automatic logon? Where does the token appear? Modern day authentication is single sign on, i.e. uses your windows login.

Comment: My apologies. I don't want an automatic login.

After the user logs in on their own I want the scrape to start.

Our companies auth is entirely web based. So you put in your username/pass, then hit okay, then it goes to another page where you MFA in.

To put it more plainly (I can get wordy) I do want the user to manually login.

Comment: .. and you want the excel doc to detect login complete and automatically scrape? It's a bit easier to have a button in excel to start the process manually . There's a link here to a tool that lets you easily add buttons to the ribbon: http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx You'll need to post some existing code so we know where to start helping. You say you can already scrape data off the page?

Comment: I actually figured it out.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for returning and posting your answer in such detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out.

```
Sub WikiScrape()

Dim oIE As Object

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
oIE.Visible = True

oIE.navigate "https://MYWEBPAGE

Application.StatusBar = "Loading Page"

Do Until oIE.document.getelementsbytagname("title")(0).innerText = "THE TITLE OF THE ACTUAL PAGE"
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Loop

While oIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
```